# coverage.em file is not getting generated after running createDebugCoverageReport with jacoco

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco

Actually I am using jacoco tool to generate my Test Coverage Report.
For this I have made following changes to my build.gradle file -:

1. Added below to build.gradle
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'
2. Added testCoverageEnabled true to build types -: 
   buildTypes {
                debug{
                   testCoverageEnabled true
                }
             }

When I am running my test using gradle command "./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport" it generates only coverage.ec file but not coverage.em file.

And as researched on StackOverflow to generate html report we need a coverage.em file as input.

Could anyone please help me in this regard ?